# Autowiring hierarchical beans

Tags: spring

Here's my scenario. I have two classes **ClassA** and **ClassB**. **ClassB** inherits **ClassA**. 

I'm using `@Component` annotation on both of them to make them Spring beans.

```
@Component
public class ClassA{
    // parent
}

@Component
public class ClassB extends ClassA{
    // child
}

public class ClassC{

    @Autowired
    private ClassA classA;

    public void doSomething(){

    }
}
```

Now, whenever I try to use `@autowired` annotation in **ClassC** to inject **ClassA** as shown above, I get the following exception.

> No unique bean of type [**ClassA**] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [**classA**, **classB**]

I understand that when auto-wiring by type, spring finds two beans that are assignable to **ClassA** and so it throws an exception.

Is there an easy way to resolve this problem apart from using `@Qualifier` annotation and auto-wiring by name?

Could I instruct spring to not only check for a bean that is assignable by type but also check to see if  it is the exact same class type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the [`@Primary`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) annotation.

If that is unfeasible and you do not want to use @Qualifier, then you will have to resolve it manually. Something like:

```
@Autowired
private List<ClassA> candidates;

private ClassA actual;

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
    for (ClassA candidate : candidates) {
        if (AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(candidate).equals(ClassA.class)) {
            actual = candidate;
            break;
        }
    }
    org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(actual , "No bean of exact type ClassA found.");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally submitted my comment before finishing. For the question I posed, using Primary annotation is the correct answer. Unfortunately, in my case ClassA and ClassB are JPA Data Repositories and Primary annotation doesn't seem to work on them. Instead I've decided to use custom qualifiers and it's working like a charm. [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/CustomAutowireConfigurer.html)